# Replace all {{ and }} without replacing {{ special_str }} in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a special field in my form which allows users to add text with `{{ special_str }}` which will be rendered by Jinja. However, I noticed that if the user uses `{{` and `}}` other than `{{ special_str }}` this will cause rendering error for Jinja.

I am trying to replace all occurrence of `{{` and `}}` but *not* `{{ special_str }}`.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: What is the current regex? Please share.

Comment: example of normal and "special" string?